# php parsing csv with ftell

Tags: php, csv

I have a 500mb csv file with over 500,000 lines, each with 80 fields. I am using fget to process the file line by line.

```
$col1 = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $col1[] = $row[0];
}
```

Because of an execution time limit on the PHP file by my hosting provider (120 seconds), I can't process the whole file in one run.

I tried using ftell() and fseek() to remember the last position for restart. The trouble is, sometimes the ftell() position is in the middle of a row, and resuming means missing the first half of the row.

Is there an elegant way to know the last line successfully processed, and resume from the one after it? I realize I can do a simple counter, and then loop through to that point again, but that would produce diminishing returns on the rows I can process towards the end of the file.

Is there something like ftell() and fseek() that would work in my case? Or a way to limit ftell() to return the pointer for the end of the previous line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i needed to work with files that big I always use the 'divide and conquer' premise. For your case I would:

Dynamicaly create a folder

Copy this big file inside it

Split it (on linux split called from php) [split command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm)

use the [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command in php

After split it, delete it (the big file)

Then loop through the files in the folder reading one by one.

And for every file I finish I delete it. So if the time limit occurs you will need just to continue reading the files left in the folder.

Comment: how would I call the split command from php? Doing it this way, wouldn't I run the same risk of chopping the file off in the middle of a record and end up with part of the record in one file, and the rest in another file?

Comment: @Robert82 I've edited the answer with the command to do that. If you put this process in a transaction (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.transactions.php) you shouldn't be concerned about it.

Comment: Ooh, I missundestood. The split command works with lines. So as you have a csv file it whould be divided by lines right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Thank you for your question! (read at the end to discover why I am so thankful)

There is some wrong/bad-choice elsewhere.
I am sure about this because I fixed code years ago that used to parse 600 thousand rows of csv in 8-9 hours, but after the fix I can read that in 8-12 seconds, depending on the system load.
I mean 12 seconds, not 120, and I mean 600,000 lines. (5 years ago, but 5 years and one month ago was 9 hours, the very next month was 12 seconds, so ...)
The most important staff here is how much memory is your script sucking, not because of the limit, but because of JUMPS. In fact jumping on huge allocated memory is the evil, most of the time your script would be swapped, and jump would means a lot of uncontrolled load (i.e. you can not profile it).

The heal for it is to **allocate as little memory as possible**.

My choicee was to rely on database buffer and transaction. In fact, from the problem I was facing, a data import, a csv import was an atomic operation.

One may think that my solution just move problem elsewhere (from php to dbms), but in fact dbms connection and its buffering is good enough to keep data in a compacted format, decide when and what to swap, and deal with memory with more expertise than PHP interpreter or my own code.

Simply put: DBMS know how to do that work.

In practice:

```
SET autocommit=0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

.. read the csv, keeping as small data as possible (**but do not query db for each line!**)

```
COMMIT;
```

### what is `ftell()`

But I should reply to this. My guess is that ftell() just return the current position read, and that `fgetcsv()` just read as much as needed to meet the first non-escaped `\n` character. How would I implement it? Well, if was a PHP author I would write some wrapper that read the buffer once, then return the each csv lines every time fgetcsv() is called. In fact you can read here

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L1831

this can make you guess how far the ftell can be from the start: you specified 1000 buffer, then the read buffer is at most 999 bytes long away from the read line (if the read line that was a "\n" line with zero column).

I do not want to read the code, but I had chosen a buffer size of 8192, that is better for os, and I think for also for php to deal with.

I am trying to answer here because I need to solve a similar problem, and you give me an hint with your concern on value returned by ftell().

My problem is to give back an hint about bad formed csv, where the chunk of data appends and so.

8192 may be an huge chunk of data, read a bad line for me means read a line with not enough columns or with too much column. In the former case I read a second line and try to put those together, if the sum is ok I can guess that first line is completed by the second one. In the later case I just give up with error. (but given that the sum is bigger, I just treat both cases as one).

Given that I applied that "trick-to-fix", I have to roll back one and an half chunk, 8192+4096, to have a quick feedback without the need to read all input file.
That is

```
fseek($fd, ftell($fd) - 12288);
$buf = fread($fd, 12288);
```

On this `$buf` then I can search for a known identifier I just read successfully for finding the failing lines

... It's a Long Way to the Top, cit. AC/DC